# Fragment Replace resulting in Overlaping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace a fragment with another one using the following code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout rootView =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    Button signupButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment signupFragment = new SignUp();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.loginFragment, signupFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

When This runs I get the two fragments overlapping on the screen. if I try calling remove() and add() instead i get the error 
[image]

Im not sure what to do to get the background fragment to disappear When the new one is added to the container.

Comment: As per your Error, you're passing fragment id in place of Fragment object.That's why you're getting this error.

Comment: Right but why are they overlapping on replace in the first place?

Comment: will you please share your xmls file too.